# How to apply between in a query in mongoose?

Tags: angular, mongodb, mongoose

I need to find values of 'from' between 'reservation.from' to 'reservation.to' in the query.

How to apply that here:

```
module.exports.findAvailability=function(reservation,callback){
    const query={      
        lab:reservation.lab,
        date:reservation.date,
        from:* //between reservation.from to reservation.to
    };

    reservationModel.find(query,callback);    
}
```

Comment: please paste your schema here.

Comment: ' const reservationSchema=new Schema({
    nic:{type:String},
    lab:{type:String},
    date:{type:Date},
    from:{type:Number},
    to:{type:Number},
    approval:{type:Boolean}
}); '

Answer (score 0):

```
let query = {
  from: {
    $gte: reservation.from,
    $lt: reservation.to
  }
}
reservationModel.find(query, callback)
```

If you got field **'from'** in your **reservationModel** , try this.

Update#1

If you want to select reservations from  - to a specific date , you should consider changing field type to `Date` instead of `Number` at **from** and **to** fields.

```
const reservationSchema=new Schema({ nic:{type:String}, lab:{type:String}, date:{type:Date}, from:{type:Date}, to:{type:Date}, approval:{type:Boolean} });
```

So the query will become:

```
let query = {
      from: {
        $gte: reservation.from
      },
      to: {
        $lt: reservation.to
      }
    }
reservationModel.find(query, callback)
```

One thing that i would suggest to find findAvailability of a reservation , you should add `from` and `to` as parameters in function , furthermore i would suggest to use moment.js library for dates manipulation.

For instance:

```
let query = {
      lab: reservation.lab,
      from: {
        $gte: moment().subtract(1, 'days')
      },
      to: {
        $lt: moment().toDate()
      }
    }
reservationModel.find(query, callback)
```

Here , i found 1 day old reservations.

All queries were tested with the provided schema.

Comment: @harin0228 feel free to leave a feedback